# Memory runs out when creating a numpy array from a list of lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I want to read in a tab separated value file and turn it into a numpy array.  The file has 3 lines.  It looks like this:

```
Ann1    Bill1   Chris1   Dick1
Ann2    Bill2   Chris2  "Dick2
Ann3    Bill3   Chris3   Dick3
```

So, I used this simple line of code:

```
new_list = []
with open('/home/me/my_tsv.tsv') as tsv:
    for line in csv.reader(tsv, delimiter="\t"):
        new_list.append(line)

new = np.array(job_posts)
print new.shape
```

And because of that pesky `"` character, the shape of my fancy new numpy array is

```
(2,4)
```

That's not right!  So, the solution is to include the argument, `quoting`, in the csv.reader call, as follows:

```
for line in csv.reader(tsv, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
```

This is great!  Now my dimension is

```
(3,4)
```

as I hoped.

Now comes the real problem -- in all actuality, I have a 700,000 X 10 .tsv file, with long fields.  I can read the file into Python with no problems, just like in the above situation.  But, when I get to the step where I create `new = np.array(job_posts)`, my wimpy 16 GB laptop cries and says...

```
MEMORY ERROR
```

Obviously, I cannot simultaneously have these 2 object in memory -- the Python list of lists, and the numpy array.

My question is therefore this:  how can I read this file directly into a numpy array, perhaps using `genfromtxt` or something similar...yet also achieve what I've achieved by using the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` argument in the csv.reader?

So far, I've found no analogy to the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` option available anywhere in the standard ways to read in a tsv file using numpy.

This is a tough little problem.  I though about iteratively building the numpy array during the reading in process, but I can't figure it out.

I tried

```
nparray = np.genfromtxt("/home/me/my_tsv.tsv", delimiter="/t")
print obj.shap
```

and got

```
(3,0)
```

If anyone has any advice I'd be greatly appreciative.  Also, I know the *real* answer is probably to use Pandas...but at this point I'm committed to using numpy for a lot of compelling reasons...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply using `genfromtxt` seems to work for me without worrying about quoting on your example, and you didn't actually show a transcript showing that it failed.  But even if quoting were an issue, wouldn't it be easiest to use `csv.writer` to make an easier-to-parse file?

Comment: I edited the question to show the results I got from using `genfromtxt`. The final solution may indeed be cleaning the file beforehand, but I am wondering if it would be possible to avoid that approach using a tool in numpy.

Comment: Matt: your edit isn't super-persuasive. :^)  You have `"/t"` where you meant `"\t"`, you're printing `obj.shap` but reading in to `nparray`, and if `obj` is an array then `obj.shap` would give an AttributeError.  It's usually best to type an example in a console and copy the whole thing, input and output, exactly.

Comment: FYI, `np.genfromtxt("my_tsv2.tsv",delimiter="\t", dtype=object)` gives me `array([['Ann1', 'Bill1', 'Chris1', 'Dick1'], ['Ann2', 'Bill2', 'Chris2', '"Dick2'], ['Ann3', 'Bill3', 'Chris3', 'Dick3']], dtype=object)`, as I think you want, but I'm using 1.9.0.dev-ef7901d and so something might have changed recently.

Comment: Believe it or not -- I did copy and paste from Pycharm (albeit missing the final 'e' from `shape` -- it was at the end...it happens!!! :)  The `\t` was a typo on my part. No wonder it gave me `(3,)`  Now my question is a mess.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work with my "real" data and the problem still persists.  I think I will post an appropriately smaller file via Dropbox with a link.

Comment: How long is long in "I have long fields"? Numpy arrays have all entries of the same type. For strings that includes the number of characters. So if you have a single field with 2,000 characters, all 7,000,000 entries of your array will save space for 2,000 characters, even if most don't need it, and that will eat up 14 GB of your memory.

Comment: @Jaime: am I correct in thinking that doesn't apply to dtype=object arrays, in which you only have the overhead of the reference to the Python string?

Comment: Yes, object arrays only hold pointers to the Python objects, so 7M entries should take no more than 56Mb on a 64bit system.